# Communicating between Activities and Fragments when using Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-components, navigation-architecture

I want to let the host Activity know when something happens in a Fragment. Traditionally, I would have an interface with a callback that the Fragment can call, but now we are ofc using the navigation architecture component.

Is there a way to pass a reference to the host activity down to the fragments or how would I otherwise solve the "Communication between activities and fragments" situation?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really want to notify the Activity of anything. If you want to share a scope between multiple Fragments, consider using a common NavGraph, and scope your ViewModel to that NavGraph's NavBackStackEntry (Navigation 2.2.0+).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you show a code sample?

Comment: See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) data holder class for such purposes.

[Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-livedata-631526d6357a) is an article explaining both `Fragment <--> Fragment` communication and `Activity <--> Fragment` communication.

Comment: That is a very good idea! Thank you! :) 

I feel like LiveData is only to store data, but why not store a `SnackbarContentModel` and let `MainActivity` observe that data and show a snackbar whenever it changes - which is my situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can have a shared ViewModel between your activity and all of your fragments. and use liveData in that viewModel. so when something happens in the fragments you change the liveData and you observe the liveData in the activity

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are right, that is a possible solution, works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Shared ViewModel (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

It would be alive while the activity is and all child fragments can access it.

A LiveData in a Shared ViewModel, for example, could be listened to in all the fragments. If one of those fragments change the data all others would get that change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are right, that is a possible solution, works like a charm! :)